# python selenium visibility of element raises TimeoutException

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

my brother asked for my lame python skills in order to build a program that monitors stocks data from nasdaq, for example - [the apple stock](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl)

I want to get the value of today's high/low(currently $ 141.3893 / $ 139.76) by `XPATH`, therefore, I use this code:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//tr[contains(lower-case(text()), 'Today's High /Low')]")))
```

My logic - find a `tr` tag that contains the text 'Today's High /Low' and then I want to print the text of the second `td`, I think this pattern is on every stock on this site.

However, it raises `TimeoutException` error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Guy Balas/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/main.py", line 49, in <module>
    main('http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/aapl')
  File "C:/Users/Guy Balas/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/main.py", line 42, in main
    s = get_data()
  File "C:/Users/Guy Balas/PycharmProjects/stockmarket/main.py", line 33, in get_data
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//td[contains(lower-case(text()), 'Today's High /Low')]"))).text
  File "C:\Users\Guy Balas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

Any other ways to achieve this/any mistake I made?

Thanks.

Comment: I've tried your xPath on the given page and it doesn't work. Your xPath seems to be wrong.

Comment: @DenisKoreyba Yeah I understand this, but do you know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as below:

```
el = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.LINK_TEXT, "Today's High /Low")))
print(el.find_element_by_xpath('./following::td').text)
```

Output `$ 141.3893 / $ 139.76`

Comment: Can you explain a bit? what is 'el' actually referring to?

Comment: `el` is referring to the variable name in the first line. It finds the element by the text in the link (`By.LINK_TEXT`). It then starts with `el` as the parent element and searches it's descendants for the second TD and prints the text of it.

Comment: @JeffC Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I know you accepted an answer but there's an easier way to do this. If you look at the HTML of the page, you will see this

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <a class="tt show-link" id="todays_high_low" onmouseover="showDelayedToolTip('todays_high_low')" onmouseout="hideToolTip('todays_high_low')" href="javascript:void(0)">
            Today's High /Low
            <span class="tooltipLG">...snip...</span>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td align="right" nowrap="">
        <label id="Label3">$&nbsp;141.3893</label>&nbsp;/&nbsp;
        <label id="Label1">$&nbsp;139.76</label>
    </td>
</tr>
```

From the HTML, you can see that the high and low each have an ID, "Label3" (high) and "Label1" (low). With that info, you can just use

```
high = WebDriverWait(driver1, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "Label3"))).text
// you don't need to wait again here since the wait should guarantee the element is accessible
low = driver1.find_element_by_id("Label1").text
```

With this method you can separate out the low from the high, which I'm assuming you are going to want to do anyway. This way avoids string processing the combined string...

Comment: Thanks, I saw the id name is pretty general so I haven't thought to try it because I figured they used it again somewhere.

Comment: I wondered the same thing so I made sure and it's unique on the page.